# In Pontypool, what language was Dr. Mendez speaking, and what did he say?

Tags: zombie, pontypool

In the excellent zombie flick, Pontypool, eventually Dr. Mendez determines that

> Speaking in a language other than English is protection against the infection. Subsequently, he speaks in another language - either babbling incoherently, or puzzling out the situation.

If it was Spanish, I couldn't understand it...I thought it might be Portugese. Can anyone identify it, and for bonus points, give me the gist of what he was saying?

Comment: If anyone else wants to take a stab at it, the movie is available on Netflix Instant and this particular scene takes place at around the 1:11:30 mark. I don't speak French so I can't translate it myself :)

Comment: I checked it out, and it's definitely not French or Spanish. It sounds Germanic, but not German...maybe Dutch. The actor himself is Armenian...he seemed pretty comfortable with the delivery - I've never heard Armenian, though.

Comment: I did trace one phrase he says several times: "ist eigen, ist eigen"! Which, in German, appears to mean "it's intrinsic". That makes sense, given what he concludes in English, but I'm not 100% sure that's the entirety of what he's speaking there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is speaking in Armenian. It's actually the western dialect of Armenian. FYI, he really doesn't say much more than "It's in the language. It is contracted from words. As long as I don't speak English, I'll probably be OK. Who would have thought the Armenian language, after all these years would have been important." I'm paraphrasing but basically this is what he is saying in Armenian, while in the broadcaster booth.

Answer (score 4):

The movie's [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontypool_%28film%29) claims that (spoilered, since I think it might give away part of the plot):

> ... Soon Dr. Mendez begins to repeat the word "breathe" but **immediately begins speaking in French**, which stifles, but not eliminates, the symptoms ...

But it doesn't specify what he says in the language.

Edit: After having watched that part of the movie myself at this point, I think Wikipedia is probably wrong; it sounds like the doctor cycles through a couple of different languages, and none of them sound particularly like French. I can't say for certain because I don't understand the languages, but he does repeat a different word a couple of times in each one; I imagine that:

> He's testing out the word "breathe" in different languages, to see if it has any effect. The fact that it doesn't leads to his discovery.